# Google map geocode getting different result in Forward API and Reverse API - In Some Addresses

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Forward API : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1045%20E%2024th%20St,%20Minneapolis,%20MN%2055404&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Result

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"1045",
               "short_name":"1045",
               "types":[
                  "street_number"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"East 24th Street",
               "short_name":"E 24th St",
               "types":[
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Phillips",
               "short_name":"Phillips",
               "types":[
                  "neighborhood",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Minneapolis",
               "short_name":"Minneapolis",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Hennepin County",
               "short_name":"Hennepin County",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Minnesota",
               "short_name":"MN",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"55404",
               "short_name":"55404",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"3833",
               "short_name":"3833",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code_suffix"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"1045 E 24th St, Minneapolis, MN 55404, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "location":{
               "lat":44.9589308,
               "lng":-93.2592956
            },
            "location_type":"RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":44.96027978029149,
                  "lng":-93.25794661970849
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":44.9575818197085,
                  "lng":-93.2606445802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id":"EioxMDQ1IEUgMjR0aCBTdCwgTWlubmVhcG9saXMsIE1OIDU1NDA0LCBVU0EiGxIZChQKEgmhxzziqTKzUhEX8ec1BmZglBCVCA",
         "types":[
            "street_address"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

and in reverse API, I used the same geometry Location Lat and Long

Reverse API: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.9589308,-93.2592956&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Result

```
{
   "plus_code":{
      "compound_code":"XP5R+H7 Minneapolis, MN, USA",
      "global_code":"86P8XP5R+H7"
   },
   "results":[
      {
         "address_components":[
            {
               "long_name":"2400",
               "short_name":"2400",
               "types":[
                  "street_number"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"11th Avenue South",
               "short_name":"11th Ave S",
               "types":[
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Midtown Phillips",
               "short_name":"Midtown Phillips",
               "types":[
                  "neighborhood",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Minneapolis",
               "short_name":"Minneapolis",
               "types":[
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Hennepin County",
               "short_name":"Hennepin County",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"Minnesota",
               "short_name":"MN",
               "types":[
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"United States",
               "short_name":"US",
               "types":[
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"55404",
               "short_name":"55404",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            },
            {
               "long_name":"3806",
               "short_name":"3806",
               "types":[
                  "postal_code_suffix"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"2400 11th Ave S, Minneapolis, MN 55404, USA",
         "geometry":{
            "bounds":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":44.9589961,
                  "lng":-93.2589414
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":44.958912,
                  "lng":-93.25912079999999
               }
            },
            "location":{
               "lat":44.958968,
               "lng":-93.2590273
            },
            "location_type":"ROOFTOP",
            "viewport":{
               "northeast":{
                  "lat":44.9603030302915,
                  "lng":-93.25768211970849
               },
               "southwest":{
                  "lat":44.9576050697085,
                  "lng":-93.2603800802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id":"ChIJTb-V4qkys1IRukelu4LNRgI",
         "types":[
            "premise"
         ]
      },
```

here I got the different Address in Reverse Google API,
Please help me out if I need to add anything in the link or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your question, you should be aware that not all addresses are presented in Google database. Sometimes address is just interpolated based on other data like street name and street numbers range, so Google can predict its position even for addresses that are missing in their database.

When you geocode some address you should check what is the location_type of the result. In your example the location_type is `RANGE_INTERPOLATED`. That means that Google doesn't have an exact ROOFTOP address in their database for the address '1045 E 24th St, Minneapolis, MN 55404' and the location was interpolated. Another clear sign of interpolated position is a very long place ID value. In your example it is `EioxMDQ1IEUgMjR0aCBTdCwgTWlubmVhcG9saXMsIE1OIDU1NDA0LCBVU0EiGxIZChQKEgmhxzziqTKzUhEX8ec1BmZglBCVCA`.

[image]

So, what happens if you now reverse geocode the coordinate of this interpolated address (44.9589308,-93.2592956)? The reverse geocoding service will prefer the existing ROOFTOP addresses and will return first closest results with location_type `ROOFTOP`and after that other interpolated results.

In your example there are several results that returns reverse geocoding. You can see them in my screenshot:

[image]

The first result (marker 1) is '2400 11th Ave S, Minneapolis, MN 55404, USA' with location type ROOFTOP, the second (marker 2) is '2408 11th Ave S, Minneapolis, MN 55404, USA' also with location type ROOFTOP, the third (marker 3) is '1005 E 24th St, Minneapolis, MN 55404, USA' again ROOFTOP and only forth result is RANGE_INTERPOLATED address '1045 E 24th St, Minneapolis, MN 55404, USA'

Note that you can ask reverse geocoding service to provide results only with certain location type. For example you can say that you are interested only in RANGE_INTERPOLATED results:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.9589308%2C-93.2592956&location_type=RANGE_INTERPOLATED&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

In this case the first result from reverse geocoding will be your range interpolated address as shown in my screenshot

[image]

I hope my answer clarifies your doubts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am strange if I got the Lat Long from the Correct addresses, then why it's changed on Reverse API, With the above example "1045 E 24th St, Minneapolis, MN 55404, USA" I got the Lat Long so its definitely in google Database, So why its getting different addressed in reverse API, I am just strange  about this

Comment: The coordinate of your address was interpolated (calculated) by Google as I explained. Google is able to guess the position of the address using their algorithms. Reverse geocoding cannot be considered as the opposite operation of geocoding, because reverse geocoding will always prefer closest ROOFTOP addresses, so in case of RANGE_INTERPOLATED result you tipically won't get back the same address.